# Word choice, specific word required

Tags: word-choice

Throughout the years, there has been an overwhelming [**tide/amount**] of controversies surrounding X.

I want to say that there has been an increase in controversies surrounding X. But I can't seem to find the right word that would fit in there with *overwhelming*.

I need a word that would mean *a lot of* as well as *an increase*. I thought *tide* works well as it has two effects to it. Picture this- a tide is progressive, going forward. And it can rise too. Is there a word that fits this?

Also, writing **Throughout the years** in the beginning, means that some has happened over the years, and so just writing '*a lot of*' does not seem to work.

Comment: Well, for starters get rid of the *overwhelming*, that's the one tripping you off. As long as it stays there you have to use something boring like *amount* or *number*, because the *overwelming* already does all the work. Once it's gone, everything will click into place and you can finally transfer that work to a nice juicy noun that has *overwhelming* as part of its definition. Like I dunno, *avalanche, barrage, flood, myriad, shitton*, or any number of others. Don't go with *tide*, tides come and go and are very shortlived. You're looking for something that keeps ploughing on and on and on.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I see, you are right about that. Thanks!

Comment: I like *barrage*, as suggested by @RegDwigнt. I was actually just about to post that as an answer, but then stopped myself when I read his comment.

Comment: @JasonBassford According to some of the dictionaries, Barrage means _A barrage of something such as criticism or complaints is a large number of them directed at someone, often in an aggressive way_ // _an overwhelming and continuous delivery of something, as words, questions, or punches_ // _a vigorous or rapid outpouring or projection of many things at once_. My question is does Barrage work with the word or idea of _controversies_ or is barrage primarily used for questions/insults etc.? Also, would it then be correct to say a barrage of controversies _surrounding_ X? Given X is a policy.

Comment: @A.Ishtiaq A *barrage of controversy* works just as well as a *barrage of criticism, complaints, or . . . bullets* in my mind. Generally, it will fit anything that implies you are overwhelmed or stunned by an onslaught of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Throughout the years, there has been an overwhelming [tide/amount] of
>   controversies surrounding X.

I suggest:

> Over time there have been **increasing** controversies surrounding X.

though I also like:

> Throughout the years, there have been a **growing** number controversies
>   surrounding X.

Others:  deluge, flood etc..

Comment: +1 for flood (seems like a good replacement for _overwhelming tide_)